# Docker hangs when pulling images or runing containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I'm facing a strange behavior using docker on Ubuntu 20.04 (I'm using this in a corporate environment).
Since 2 days, I'm completely unable to run containers or even pull images from Docker Hub.

When trying to pull any image from Docker Hub (even the hello-world), the image is downloaded locally and then docker freezes as you can see on the following picture
[image: docker run hello-world]

I first tried to restart the docker daemon and even the machine (as this is my development computer) => NOK.

Then I tried to completely reinstall the docker package and all its dependencies using the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge docker docker.io
sudo apt autoremove --purge docker docker.io
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo rm -rf /etc/docker
rm -rf ~/.docker
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Result => NOK.

The next step was to reinstall my Ubuntu 20.04 machine => NOK.

I also tried to limit simultaneous connections of docker daemon to only one as I read on some forums some people have experienced similar problems and they solved this by limiting simultaneous connections => NOK

I tried to move the location of the docker root folder by adding the following content to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`  => NOK.

```
{
   "data-root": "/var/lib/docker"
}
```

I added `--debug` flag to dockerd command line to get more info on what's happening and here is what I get when I try to run hello-world container:

```
sept. 09 16:09:38 dockerd[1842]: time="2021-09-09T16:09:38.582649566+02:00" level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:b8dfde127a2919ff59ad3fd4a0776de178a555a76fff77a506e128aea3ed41e3\""
sept. 09 16:09:39 dockerd[1842]: time="2021-09-09T16:09:39.290277164+02:00" level=debug msg="Downloaded b8dfde127a29 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob129841538"
sept. 09 16:09:39 dockerd[1842]: time="2021-09-09T16:09:39.290586225+02:00" level=debug msg="Using /usr/bin/unpigz to decompress"
sept. 09 16:09:39 dockerd[1842]: time="2021-09-09T16:09:39.296254339+02:00" level=debug msg="Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/91e5944b0c0d34d010b4f28036e29d47213266af5677660edbb00470160fb186/diff" storage-driver=overlay2
```

The blob is present into `/var/lib/docker/tmp` and the folder `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/91e5944b0c0d34d010b4f28036e29d47213266af5677660edbb00470160fb186/diff` is created but is empty.

Comment: Try installing from the Docker repo:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Hello SiHa, sorry I forgot to mention that I also tried to get the latest docker version from the Docker repo, unfortunately with no success :-(

Comment: Well, I'd try to figure that out, if I were you. It's a straightforward process, which I have followed many times with no issues (including on Ubuntu20.04 in both bare server and WSL2 incarnations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem origin was a bad configuration of the docker so that it can work into our corporate network.
After flushing the docker once again => reinstall => reconfigure completely => OK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Facing the same problem. @nicoh, could you expand on "bad configuration"?

Answer (score 0):

Have experienced a very similar behavior and similar debug output. Also in a corporate environment. The following [WSL issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6837) suggested that it might be related to the anti-virus program. In my case turning of the anti-virus program "solved" the problem.